# change locale programmatically

Tags: iphone

HI all,

i hv a table view showing 4 languages
english,spanish,german and french,

i created xib's for each view, also created Localizable.strings.
everything is working fine when i change language from simulator.
whole app gets changed according to language selected..

what i m trying to do is,instead of changing language from simulator's directory of language,
i want to change language through my table view,which shows languages.
if i tap on table with spanish values, whole app should changes its language.

can we do this.

like simulator's language setting changes language of whole simulator,
i want to change language of my app through my app.

hope for a quick reply

help is always appreciated

regards
shishir

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following thing.

```
NSArray *languages = nil;

languages = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *localizedStr = NSLocalizedString(@"ABOOK", @"Hello");
NSLog(@"String 11 = %@", localizedStr);
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This is totally not working for me :-/

Comment: This works for me ! After setting using the above function. give a try `NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String`