# Xcode: Run project with specified localization

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, localization, xib

My Cocoa project is localized in Italian (my language) and English language.
If I run it, i see everything in Italian (of course, my OS is italian!).
How can I run it to test the English localization without changing the OS language?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the old times, Leopard and before,  the get info window in Finder would let
you choose  the available  languages. So  it was a  matter of  deselecting the
language that you don't want to use and it would "default" to the other.

These days you can use an utility like [this one](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/). I'd love to know what it
does behind the scenes though.

---

I finally found  a nice solution in the [cocoa-dev  mailing list archives](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/3862-changing-language-at-runtime.html).
Apparently, you can  change the default domain within the  arguments passed to
your executable, and  this causes the global preference to  be overwritten. It
can be achieved with the `-AppleLanguages`  flag, pass a list of the languages
in the preferred order:

```
~/apath/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName -AppleLanguages "(Italian, English)"
```

Run this from your terminal and it  should give a different precedence for the
language.  Notice you  can also  specify a  single element  list `"(Italian)"`
—makes more sense for testing purposes.

To do it within  Xcode and avoid the terminal, go to the  menu *Product > Edit
Scheme…* . Then, in your run configuration switch to the *Arguments* tab and
create a  new one to be  passed on launch. Add  `-AppleLanguages "(Japanese)"`
text to it. Something similar to this:

[image: Xcode Screen Shot]

Comment: @sidyll this is a nice solution. I'm going to try it on iOS when I get a chance - it would save the same hassle of changing the device language all the time.

Comment: even better! :D thank you very much (and we discovered how languageswitcher works ;D)

Comment: @Oneiros glad to help! And yeah, this is probably the trick behind it.

Comment: Thanks @Jessedc . Once you test it, let me know about the results in iOS. I didn't find any to documentation regarding this "feature". I'll keep looking.

Comment: Thanks @Jessedc , nice to know. I'll let you know when I find where is this documented :-)

Comment: Thank you, such a brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file that holds all the strings, swap the names of the files.  Or, if you've got a it.lproj and en.lproj group in your project, just move your InfoPlist.strings (or whatever you named it) into the other group and vice versa.

Comment: thanks, useful trick. hadn't thought about it :D any other suggestions?

Comment: Yup, just edited my response with a little more info.  In my case, I use a special file name, but you may be using localized groups with the same file name, in which case you just place the en.lproj string file into the it.lproj group for example. Of course, you will want to move them back before you deploy :D

Comment: Then you might consider changing it programmatically for debug purposes.  I found this question that may be helpful for you: [change locale programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022628/change-locale-programmatically)