# Preview Interface Builder Layout on iPad and iPhone

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-universal-app

Using Xcode 5, I've created a new `xib` that I want to use for both the iPad and iPhone versions of my app. Is there a way I can use the Assistant to preview the layout for both devices?

I created the `xib` file using `New File` > `User Interface` > `View` but it forces me to choose either iPad or iPhone. I don't see the option for "Universal"

Comment: As far as I know, right now you can only preview your xib in iOS 7 and iOS6, rotate it and select 3.5 screen. No more than that. But there is a featured question somehow similar to this and you're probably interested in reading it and the few answers up to today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857046/how-to-preview-storyboard-in-xcode-using-non-base-localisation. A preview for localised views and iPad / iPhone would be a really great improvement to have for developers.

Comment: I could care less about localized view.. but would really love ability to switch between iPhone and iPad in IB preview (or just let me pick any/custom resolution so I can quickly preview/check my auto-layout constraints/etc).