# How do I add the iPad view option to Xcode preview?

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

In my main Swift iOS app I see in Xcode the preview pane and it lets me add various iPhone and iPad devices successfully and view the selected UI View Controller in my app storyboard.

In my Today extension preview I can only add iPhone devices, not the iPad.

[image]

Any ideas?

Works fine for the main app:

[image]

Devices appear fine in simulator:

[image]

Universal app:

[image]

Comment: Might remark on the design: Apple's quite strict about it, and the design shown here will mean the app gets rejected from Apple's submission process.

Answer (score -2):

[How to preview Storyboard in Xcode using Non-Base localisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857046/how-to-preview-storyboard-in-xcode-using-non-base-localisation)        ----> check it and enable UseAutolayout Opention , and size Classes