# What image size need to print a full A4 paper with UIPrintInteractionController?

Tags: ios, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintpagerenderer, uiprintformatter, uiprintinfo

Printing logic look like this:

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printController.printInfo = printInfo
printController.showsNumberOfCopies = false
printController.printingItem = image
printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Which size image needs to use all the A4 size paper?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiprintpaper) the paper size chosen by locale.

When using `UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral` either US Letter size or A4 is picked, depending on user locale.

Comment: Do you know how can I change US Letter to A4? Need to change user locale settings?

Comment: Yes you need to change the locale

Comment: I have (1) Hungarian (2) English (U.K.) set as language

Comment: It regards the system locale, are you testing on the simulator?

Comment: Nope, on device with real printer.

Comment: You need to check the locale within the settings of your device. Or you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014295/4019540) to force it

Comment: Checked: (1) Hungarian (2) English (U.K.) **NOT** English US

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014295/4019540) to force it. But in any case, there is a different issue at hand, one regarding your locale as the documentation clearly states papersize is determined by locale.